# Problems with jumping animation

Tags: android, libgdx, 2d-games, aide-ide

I made a jumping animation but when i stop touching the screen, the animation stops.

Here is the code:

```
    boolean touching = Gdx.input.isTouched();
    long elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)%1000;

    if (touching){
        float jump = 500 * (float)Math.sin(((Math.PI*2)/1000)*(elapsed/2));
        sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,jump);
    }
```

How do i make the animation finish after i stop touching the screen?

Here is a gif of the code running:

[image]

Comment: your current result `stop touching the screen, the animation stops.` and you want to achieve `animation finish after i stop touching the screen`, what is difference between these two, I think only of word `stop` and `finish` ?

Comment: When i stop touching, the sprite freezes in the air. But i want it to finish the animation until it hits the ground

Comment: okay got it, already answered check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve is to jump by a single touch and let it finish. I would use somekind of state to do this. Currently, the code within your statement only runs when touching.

Whenever a user touches the screen you could set a `boolean jumping` to `true`. Then instead of checking `if (touching)` you check for `if (jumping)`. Here you put the code for the jump. When someone presses the screen while jumping you should not allow it to reset (except in the case of something like a double jump). And whenever the entity touches the ground again jumping should be set back to `false`.